# Given the quadrupole moment of the nucleus as Q, is it possible to find the order of magnitude of the dimensions of the nucleus?

Tags: particle-physics, nuclear-physics

Given the quadrupole moment of the nucleus as Q, is it possible to find the order of magnitude of the dimensions of the nucleus? ( order of magnitude means approximate value to the powers of ten)

Comment: You mean the [tensor $Q_{i,j}$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadrupole#Mathematical_definition)?

Comment: Yes. @KyleKanos

Comment: My guess is probably not based solely on $Q_{i,j}$, but I'm not entirely sure.

Answer (score 1):

When someone refers to the quadrupole moment of a nucleus, they usually assume cylindrical symmetry and are referring to the $zz$ component of the tensor $Q_{ij}$: $$<Q_{zz}> = 3z^{2}-r^2$$
For a spherical nucleus, $<Q_{zz}>=0$, but this doesn't mean it has no size. So no, in general you can't get an estimate of the size of the nucleus from the quadrupole moment.